# Bound Parameter Type to only accept Context Object not Activity Object

Tags: android, android-context, bounded-wildcard

```
public static <T extends Context> APIInterface getServiceInstance(T context) {

    if (apiInterface == null) {

      // do Something
    }

    return apiInterface;
}
```

**This method is currently accepting all the objects** .. Activity.this .. getApplicationContext(), getContext() and getBaseContext()

***Can we restrict this method to only accept Context object as a parameter / not Activity.***

Thanks

Comment: [`Context` is `abstract`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context). The only instances you can have will be of subclasses.

Comment: i m ok with these methods getApplicationContext(), getContext() and getBaseContext(). But not activity object. Is there any method we can bound/restrict parameter.

Comment: This  implementation is correct, activity is also a subclass of Context

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!context instanceof Activity) {
      //Your code
   }else{
      throw new RuntimeException("Text exception");
  }
```

This code verifies that context is not an activity context.

Comment: I can do this verification inside the method body.But  I m talking about to restrict parameter itself. So then if someone call this methods like this getServiceInstance (Activity.this). He must get compile time error. How i can achieve this :).

Comment: I'm afraid this is impossible, it would be better if you check if the context is not an activity context, otherwise throw an exception

Comment: Why don't you want to do type checking and throw an exception otherwise?

Comment: The problem in your method is if i will call this method 200 times in my project on different classes. i need to handle that exception every where. Alternative i can find. But i was thinking that may be i can get some efficient approach here. And secondly with your above code we will get compile time error. Little modification need   if (!(context instanceof Activity)) {

        }
        else throw  new RuntimeException("");

Comment: why do you need to check the activity context?

Comment: As we know in android we have different context. Some Resources are related to  Application Context and Some Resources are related to Activity Context and so on. So if i only want to call those resources in this method that's a part of application context. So that's why i was trying to do this . :)

Comment: why don’t you just get the application context out of the ordinary context?